# Create a method or a service for a requirement with similar estructure

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a custom LOG in my angular app (typescript).
When you press some action buttons.

The body of the log is the following one:

- today date (YYYY-MM-DD)
- actual time (hh:mm:ss)
- environment name (env1, ... , env5)
- method action (extraction or download)
- description (Extraction in env1 or download in env1)

My current implementation is the next one:

## MyComponent

```
extraction(): void {
// bla bla bla code
this.loggerService.setMessage(setExtractionMessage());
console.log(this.loggerService.getMessage());
}

download(): void {
// bla bla bla code
this.loggerService.setMessage(setDownloadMessage());
console.log(this.loggerService.getMessage());
}

setDownloadMessage(): string {
const date = ...;
const time = ...;
const env = ...;
// same with all the constants

finalLog += date + time + env ...;
return finalLog;
} 

setExtractionMessage(): string {
const date = ...;
const time = ...;
const env = ...;
// same with all the constants

finalLog += date + time + env ...;
return finalLog;
}
```

## LoggerService.ts

```
setMessage(message: string) {
    this.message = '';
    this.message = message;
  }

  getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
```

Do have any suggestions for improving my implementation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would give more responsibilities to Logger Service. define an Enum of all types of messages, define the type of message, send the parameters and let the logger service do the job.

```
enum Messages: {
    extraction,
    download,
    other
}
```

### **your component:**

```
extraction(): void {
// bla bla bla code
this.loggerService.logger(Messages.extraction, parameters);
}

download(): void {
// bla bla bla code
this.loggerService.logger(Messages.download, parameters);
}
```

### LoggerService

```
logger(type, parameters: any[]){
    switch(type) {
        case Messages.extraction:
        finalLog = parameters.map(t => ''+t).join(', ');
        console.log(finalLog);
        break;

        case Messages.download:
        finalLog = parameters.map(t => ''+t).join(', ');
        console.log(finalLog);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I will refactor my code based on your solution.
 Do you know what map does? Is it similar to what I was using with the string?
I mean this:
message += message1 + message2...

Comment: no problem Albert. no i just used map to make sure every item of parameters is string. actually join do that part of combining items of array for you.

Comment: a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

string = a.join(', '); // string will be 'a, b, c'

Comment: The only problem is that some parameters should have this '-' separator and others should have this ';'

Comment: so you can make use of map in that case:

finalLog = parameters.map(t => this.needsCharacter(t)? t + '-' :  t+'').join();